# Are users able to edit the data stored in the Google Drive AppData folder?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm building an application and I wanted to store a user's secret in their own Google Drive in their own AppData folder. This is the link to the docs: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/appdata

The docs say this:

> Use this folder to store any files that the user shouldn't directly interact with

I'm trying to seek clarification on the use of the word "directly"

Assuming that the user doesn't have access to my application's client secret is the user able to modify the files that my application stores in the appdata folder in their Google Drive using the Google Drive API on their own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `Use this folder to store any files that the user shouldn't directly interact with` means that:

- the user does not have access to the folder via UI
- the user cannot access the folder programmatically outside of the App and scopes that created this folder
- the user will have indirect access as implemented by your App - e.g. if your code includes a functionality that creates / reads / modifies data in the app folder when a user clicks a button - then the user performs an indirect interaction when clicking on the button

Comment: Yep, just what i wanted to confirm. Thank you!